# which platform to choose for designing a game

Tags: game-design, software-engineering

I am new to gaming platform and don't have any experience in gaming as well. I want to develop a small shooting game and don't have any idea from where to start and which platform to use like things. I have some experience in java and .net. Can anyone help me in giving me a start? I don't mind even if this question is voted down or closed. But please do help me. I've tried searching other similar questions but everyone is already into gaming and i can't get any of the words. Please refer me to some books or tutorials

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. Searching similar questions is always a good idea, but I think you've missed the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) in doing so. The first item has a list of questions that are not a good fit to the Q&A format of SE (like yours, as you were probably already expecting, because there is no definitive answer), and they link through to resources that might be more helpful at giving you an answer.

Comment: I disagree about the definitive answer, as I see it, he has some knowlegde about .net and wants to create a shooting game. This narrows down platforms and frameworks quite a bit. Especially when it needs to have a low threshold to start out with.

Comment: Since you know C#, you may find this link useful http://pabdulin.blogspot.ru/2012/04/set-of-xna-tutorinals-beginner-shouldnt.html

Comment: Thanks Eric for responding. I also tried searching google since yesterday but without any result. I don't have any other choice than SE which i trust the most

Comment: @Thomas These questions are closed as off topic because they're often extremely localized to the asker, as well as being chatty and open-ended and having no definitive answer. Whilst one could suggest to him a platform (in fact, one could suggest several, as well as suggest other languages and so on), this is not a fit for GDSE's Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at XNA or Unity.
XNA is perfect if you have some c# knowledge, its free and there are plenty of resources out there.

I'dont have any experience with Unity so I cannot describe pro's and con's and major differences between them, but I found XNA to be pretty complete and easy to begin with.